# osx build ffmpeg for android

Tags: android, macos, build, ffmpeg

I want to build ffmpeg source code for android platform.

And i had followed some tutorials, but build failed.

here are my configs

1. build_android.sh file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   NDK=/Users/***/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r14b
   SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
   TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
   function build_one
   {
       ./configure 
       --prefix=$PREFIX 
       --enable-shared 
       --disable-static 
       --disable-doc 
       --disable-ffmpeg 
       --disable-ffplay 
       --disable-ffprobe 
       --disable-ffserver 
       --disable-avdevice 
       --disable-doc
       --disable-symver 
       --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 
       --target-os=linux 
       --arch=arm 
       --enable-cross-compile 
       --sysroot=$SYSROOT 
       --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" 
       --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" 
       $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
       make clean
       make
       make install
   }
   CPU=arm
   PREFIX=$(pwd)/androidtest/$CPU
   ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
   build_one
   ```
2. configure file

   I have also changed `configure` file

change

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR) $(SLIBNAME)'
```

to

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)-$(LIBMAJOR)$(SLIBSUF)'  
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB)"$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'  
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)'  
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME)'
```

3. console output

> ```
> ...
> INSTALL   doc/examples/demuxing_decoding.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/encode_audio.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/encode_video.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/extract_mvs.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/filter_audio.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/filtering_audio.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/filtering_video.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/http_multiclient.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/hw_decode.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/metadata.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/muxing.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/qsvdec.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/remuxing.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/resampling_audio.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/scaling_video.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/transcode_aac.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/transcoding.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/vaapi_encode.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/vaapi_transcode.c
> INSTALL   doc/examples/README
> INSTALL   doc/examples/Makefile
> INSTALL   libavdevice/libavdevice.a
> /bin/sh: ranlib/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a: No such file or directory
> make: *** [install-libavdevice-static] Error 127
> ```

4. problem

according to the console output, `libavdevice.a` not found.

[image]

but I can find it in the finder

how to fix `/bin/sh: ranlib/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a: No such file or directory`  error ?

i have searched some resolvers for `make: *** [install-libavdevice-static] Error 127` but not work for me.

Comment: You don't need `make install` for cross-platform

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. Although it was solved, I still don't know the exact reason.
I encountered this error when using the NDK that was downloaded in Android Studio and ffmpeg 4.0. The solution was to replace ffmepg with the 3.3.7 version and re-download the r14 version of ndk instead of using the one provided in Android studio. Hope this is useful to you.
[ndk下载链接](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/?hl=zh-cn)

Comment: Yes, I am also facing trouble with FFmpeg 3.4.1 and NDK r17.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look at your configure file to see if a space is missing. If so then make
`'$$(RANLIB)"$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"' -> '$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'`